clojure map transformation with Input values from sequence
Need Help in transforming data from map using a function
(defn transform-map-1 [past-step dir]
  (cond (= dir "v")
        (list (first (first past-step))
              (+ -1 (first (first past-step))))
        (= dir "^")
        (list (first (first past-step))
              (+ 1 (first (first past-step))))
        (= dir ">")
        (list (+ 1 (first (first past-step)))
              (first (first past-step)))
        (= dir "<")
        (list (+ -1 (first (first past-step)))
              (first (first past-step)))))

This function takes two input co-ordinates in x,y format as past step and dir up down left right to give the updates co-ordinates
what I would like to do have a series of directions and for each dir return updated co-ordinates
Input Sting "^>v<" , output should be ((0,1) (1,1) (1,0) (0,0)
we start with co-ordinates (0.0) Output from the first transformation becomes the input for the second char
The best I could come for is but it gives me an error
(map (transform-map-1 ['(0, 0)] %1)(char-array string-test))


You were close with your implementation.
The issues I see are:

The %1 in your call to transform-map-1 is valid only in an anonymous function which uses this format: #( ... use %1 %2 %3 etc inside)

Your function expects the direction to be a String, but mapping over a String will result in an iteration over a sequence of Characters, which is not what your function expects. One trick to turn a single String into multiple 1-character Strings is (map str your-string), which uses str to turn each Char into a String.


With those two changes, the call to your function will look like this:
(def test-string "^>v<")

(map #(transform-map-1 ['(0, 0)] %1) (map str test-string))
;; returns: ((0 1) (1 0) (0 -1) (-1 0))

There are other things you can learn later on that could help you solving your puzzle:

Destructuring will help you break apart the arguments in the individual components and give them names so they are easier to work on
Style: most Clojure devs would represent a pair of coordinates as a 2-sized vector which can be written with square brackets: [x y]
Reduce: If you have a function that performs a single step, you can reduce a collection containing the movements and obtain the final position. With reductions you can also obtain all the intermediate steps, if you need the full trail.


one minor issue with this solution is I see it does not take the output from the first reduction as input to the second one . tested with string "^v^v^v^v^v", I was expecting ((0,1) (0,0)(0,1) etc) , basically the user just moving up and down

@developer2015 that is the point of map - if you want to build up a result, that is not 1:1, use reduce (ike suggested in the final paragraph)
